# Marketing Cloud list import

Tags: marketing-cloud, import, subscriber-key

My company is migrating ESP from Listrak to Marketing Cloud and my boss asked me to export all of our lists from Listrak and get them on Marketing cloud. I notice when I try to import the Listrak list into either a saved MC list or data extension, it tells me a subscriber key is required and to map one of the fields from the .csv to subscriber field/record.

Listrak doesn't use subscriber keys so I'm puzzled at either how to generate one for each contact we're trying to bring over or if there is a better way to bring the list over.

Comment: What was the unique identifier you were using for Listrak? You would want to use that for the subscriberkey. But also if you are looking to integrate with a CRM like SF Core, etc. you would likely want to then associate the subscriberkey with the unique identifier there instead.

Comment: The unique identifier in Listrak is the email address. When I import into MC, it requires mapping BOTH email and subscriber key, but will not let me select the same source for both.

Comment: I have referred you to an old answer I have provided earlier, on this topic - on why using email address as subscriber key is a bad idea. The post, however, does not answer HOW to generate a subscriber key not being an email address. This very much depends on the system landscape, the communication channels in question (are you e.g. using both email and sms), as well as your technical skills.

Comment: Yeah to use Email Address as Subkey you would have to create a second duplicate column of Email Address in your files so you can map it twice. This is not the greatest of ideas though as Lukas pointed out and although may be easier now, can have major issues as you scale your needs.

Comment: Ok so, what is the best way to get my mailing list from Listrak into salesforce marketing cloud? I just want to be able to send these people email blasts like a normal regular ESP allows.

Comment: There is a lot to consider when first building your contacts so we cannot answer that for you. If you are looking at simplest, you can just duplicate the email address field like i said. Also, most 'normal regular' ESPs do a LOT to ensure you do not do 'email blasts' as that is likened to spam and instead push for relevant and personalized messaging to your audience. SFMC is not a batch and blast system and you will have a lot of difficulty if you try to use it like that. I would highly recommend doing some research before moving your data in to help set yourself up for success.